# Always Scroll to bottom in vertical scroll bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `flowlayoutpanel` in my winform in which the images are added dynamically. I want the `vertical scroll bar` to always be at the bottom showing the last image added. How can i do that?
I have

`AutoScroll = true`

`FLow Direction = Top Down`

`Wrap Content = False`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scrollable container controls, like FlowLayoutPanel, automatically keep the control with the focus in view.  But PictureBox is special, it cannot receive the focus.  So you have to help by explicitly asking the FLP to make the added control visible, use its ScrollControlIntoView() method.  Like this:

```
    var pic = new PictureBox();
    //...
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pic);
    flowLayoutPanel1.ScrollControlIntoView(pic);
```

With the strong advantage that this works for *any* layout setting you applied to the FLP.  You can also tinker with the AutoScrollPosition property, but it is harder to get that right:

```
    flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(
        pic.Right  - flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
        pic.Bottom - flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
```

Comment: thnx. It did the work. i can use both method since i have linklabel below picturebox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scrollBar.Value=scrollBar.Maximum;
```

here scrollBar is your ScrollBar control in winform.

For more detail, [check this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to force the last control into view.

```
        flowLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(Control_To_Add); // Control_To_Add is the control we want to scroll to
        Button TempButton = new Button();
        TempButton.Width = _Panel.ClientRectangle.Width - 6; // Make the last control in the _Panel
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(TempButton); // We add this TempButton so we can scroll to the bottom of the _Panel.Controls
        flowLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(b); // We scroll to TempButton at the bottom of the _Panel.Controls
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(b); // We remove TempButton
        b.Dispose(); // clean up
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing A FlowLayoutPanel to scroll to and display all of a control.
Code Correction:

```
flowLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(Control_To_Add); // Control_To_Add is the control we want to scroll to
Button TempButton = new Button();
TempButton.Width = _Panel.ClientRectangle.Width - 6; // Make the last control in the _Panel
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(TempButton); // We add this TempButton so we can scroll to the bottom of the _Panel.Controls
flowLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(TempButton); // We scroll to TempButton at the bottom of the _Panel.Controls
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(TempButton); // We remove TempButton
b.Dispose(); // clean up
```

Comment: b.Dispose(); should be TempButton.Dispose()

Comment: Using the Scroll event works well if you want it to occur every time there is a Scroll event , however the code presented here can be called at any time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
MyControl uct = new MyControl();
uct.Parent = flowLayoutPanel;

this.ActiveControl = uct;



if (flowLayoutPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible)
{
    flowLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(uct);
}
```